# Using an alias name multiple times in SQL query?

Tags: sql, alias

I use the same alias (RankedPrice) twice in my query. I expected that to cause an error. But it worked well. Why does this happen ? I was expecting it throw a variable scope error like C++ or Java, but it does not happen.

```
select *
from
(select *, RANK() over(order by retailprice) as RankedPrice
from CurrentProducts) as RankedPrice
where RankedPrice = 5
```

Comment: One is a table alias and the other is a column alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way that SQL works, you can never have any confusion about what *type* of object you're referencing, in any particular reference.

If you have `SELECT a, ...`, you know that `a` is a reference to a column. It can't be a reference to a table, a database, a stored procedure, a UDF, etc.(*)

If you have `SELECT a.b, ...`, you know that `a` is a reference to a table(+), and that `b` is a reference to a column.(*)

So, there's no logical reason to preclude a table from containing a column where both the table and the column have the same name.

---

(*) - this applies in the `SELECT` clause. In the `FROM` clause, a single-part name can only be a table(+), a two-part name can only be schema + table, etc. But in each clause, the type of objects being referenced is always unambiguous.

(+) - well, what I really mean here is a row source - a table, a view, a CTE. Something that, if you wanted to, you could construct as a table and use in its place in the query.

---

As others have said, there's also no obstacle to introducing the same alias in a subquery. But that's not happening here, because we end up with an object that can (properly) be referenced as `RankedPrice.RankedPrice`.

Answer (score 1):

Parent and nested subqueries have different namespaces for aliases. It is therefore okay for nested subqueries to use the same aliases, but it might be a bit confusing for someone reading the code.

That said in your code `RankedPrice` is used first as a column alias and then as a derived table alias, though the aforementioned namespace sepreration prevents any collisions.

I should also point out that correlated subqueries have a single shared namespace.